# Is it possible to alter an external variable in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For instance:

```
n = 0
i = [n=n+1 for x in range(1,(12*8)+1) if x % 2 == 0]
```

This is just a silly question, I don't have any real use for this. I could use a for or while loop to achieve something similar. I'm just interested if this is possible. (Which is assume it's not haha.)

Comment: what is the output expected.... I am a bit confused here....

Comment: Did you try it? Did it error?

Comment: His range expression sucks for exemplifying, but I assume that (replacing it for `range(1,5)` ), OP wants `i` to be [1,2,3,4]; and `n` to be 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make assignments within list comprehension bodies. The language specification only allows [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comprehension). However, this means that you *can* call methods that have side effects. For example, you could call `list.append` to modify a different list, e.g.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> [lst.append(i) for i in range(5)]
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But this is very rarely useful, and most of the times ends up in a more confusing expression. It’s far more recommended to just split it up to a standard for loop then; this also avoids the overhead of the generated list.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was just a stupid useless idea I had and I wanted to see if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.  In Python expressions cannot assign, and assignments do not act as values.  Therefore, your code produces a syntax error.

What you can do instead, if you are just interested in `n`:

```
from collections import Counter

n = Counter(True for x in range(1, (12*8)+1) if x % 2 == 0)[True]
```

If you are just interested in `i`, go with @poke's answer:

```
i = []
[i.append(x) for x in range(1, (12*8)+1) if x % 2 == 0]
i
```

That said, expressions don't have to be side-effect-free.  If you want both `i` and `n`, you can do this:

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def incr(self):
        self._value += 1
        return self._value

    def __int__(self):
        return self._value

n = Count(0)
i = [n.incr for x in range(1, (12*8) + 1) if x % 2 == 0]
n = int(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late to the party but I just had a similar coding problem (getting a max sub-array from another in O(n), so I wanted both the new array and its total in one pass, not using sum) and you can by defining a custom function :

```
n = 0
def inc_n(x):
  global n
  n += 1
  return x

i = [inc_n(x) for x in range(1,(12*8)+1) if x % 2 == 0]
```